# Interaction between classes

Tags: actionscript-3, oop

In my main Actionscript file i have a instance of a body class that moves the person body arms legs etc. and a gun class which has methods and properties to do with the person gun.

Right now i have a function in the Main class which is called move gun and looks like this and is called everyframe to move the gun to the bodys arm. I was hoping to move this function to the guns class so i could call it like gun.moveGun(); but the body dosent exist inside the gun variable. so i wonder if i could call the body.getArm(); function from inside the gun. I know i could call the function and pass the bodys arm location to it from the main file. But don't know if this is the best way to do it.

```
private function moveGun():void
    {
        gun.x = body.getArm('left').x;
        gun.y = body.getArm('left').y;
    }
```

It seems like keeping the gun related functions inside the gun class is the best way to organise everything but i dont know how to do this.

Also depending what button someone clicks at the start the person will either have a basketBall or gun in there hand. Ive added the swf online at  [Here](http://michaelboothj.co.cc) so you can see how it works. i just wanna change how its organised because the main file is very full and though i should learn how to organise things better. There are lots of other part of the program that would be organised better if i knew how to get the object to interact or what is the best way to do it. Starting to think passing the x,y coordinates to the moveGun function inside the gun Class is the best way. If so just tell me please and ill do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the code you posted, I think you need to move the gun with every frame to stick to the player's arm.

The answer you're looking for is Composition, since every person gets one and only one gun, I think you better put a reference (variable) in the person class for its gun.

and here is your player (person) class:

```
class Person
{
    private var m_gun:Gun;

    public function Person()
    {
        this.m_gun = new Gun();
    }

    // a function which is called each frame
    private function updateFrame()
    {
        // Here you can provide your own logic in Gun class
        this.m_gun.doSomething();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks this seems like the way to go. But for my program depending what button the user clicks at the beginning the person will either have a ball of a ball class in there hand moving on every frame, or a gun so if i have the gun variable in the body class i wont be able to do this. But thanks for your answer i never though about doing this before and think it will be useful to know for the future.

Comment: @user531186 Then you may combine my answer with the other answer and use dispatchEvent to solve your problem.

Comment: Ok just tried this and it doesn't really help. Right now in my main class i have the code for moving the gun to the body's arm everyframe. and with it changed like that it means id have to do it in the body's class. I was wanting to do it in the gun class to keep all the gun related stuff there to make it more organised then having everything in the main code. But thanks for the suggestion im sure it'll help with something someday.

Comment: I'm glad it helped, But wait, you don't put the gun moving logic in the main class, you let a class be the Document class, let's consider it the Game class and from that you call player logic, OK, the player has a gun, from the player you call the gun moving logic. I think the picture is complete now.

Answer (score 0):

generally, you want to communicate between classes using the built-in event listener and dispatcher system.  if 'something' happens - regardless of 'where' that occurs - dispatch an event.  whenever something should react, it should have a listener.

for example, from the main class you mentioned, you might want to dispatch an event:

```
private function moveGun():void
{
var e:Event = new Event('moveGun', true);
dispatchEvent(e);
}
```

then the appropriate instance (the body? - not sure how you have things set up) listen for that:

```
body.addEventListener('moveGun', moveGunHandler, false, 0, true);
function moveGunHandler(event:Event):void{
  gun.x = body.getArm('left').x;
  gun.y = body.getArm('left').y;
}
```

the above is obviously psuedo-code since i have no way of knowing how your display list is set up.  also, i used simple string literal event types - best practice would probably be to use custom event classes with event types defined as static constants.